# Why does substracting -1 in shader fail for a float data type?

Tags: texture, glsl, mathematics, webgl, fragment-shader

I am loading a texture in a WebGL fragment shader (GLSL version 1.00).

This is my working code:

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying float v_coord;

void main(void) {
  float inv_coord;
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_coord, 0.5));
}
```

`v_coord` holds the texture coordinates for each vertex. What I'm trying now, is to invert the texture coordinates. I thought about something like `abs(v_coord - 1)`. However, whenever I try to substract `- 1` from `v_coord`, my shader fails to compile.

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying float v_coord;

void main(void) {
  float inv_coord = v_coord - 1; // fails here
  inv_coord = abs(inv_coord);
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(inv_coord, 0.5));
}
```

Why does substracting minus one in fragment shader fail for a float data type? How to invert the texture coordinate value correctly?

Comment: "fails to compile" is kinda useless without the error messages, check the `shaderInfoLog` and/or the `programInfoLog` after attempting the compile and link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing the error message I can't be sure but I think it's failing on the 1 being int instead of a float.

```
float inv_coord = v_coord - 1.0;
```

There is a simpler method, you can do `1.0 - v_coord` and do away with the abs.

Comment: More annoyingly, this fails on only some drivers/cards, which makes it hard to debug in the wild. As best practice, never rely on implicit casts to float in GLSL, always specify the decimal dot.